# Find the fermion mass by looking at the Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, mass, fermions

We have a Lagrangian of the form:

$$\mathcal{L} = \overline{\psi} i \gamma_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \psi - g \left( \overline{\psi}_L \psi_R \phi + \overline{\psi}_R \psi_L \phi^* \right) + \mathcal{L}_{\phi} - V(|\phi|^2) $$

Essentially, what we are studying is spontaneous symmetry breaking. First, we must find the minimum of $V(|\phi|^2)$ to determine the vacuum state. We obtain:

$$
\langle \phi \rangle = v = \sqrt{\frac{m^2}{\lambda}}
$$

Now, let's perform the following expansion:

$$
\phi = (v + h(r, t)) \exp (-\frac{i \pi(r, t)}{f})
$$

Now, the question arises: How do we find the mass of the "new particles," $\pi$ and $h$? This part is straightforward. However, the challenge lies in determining the fermion mass, denoted as $m_{\psi}$, and its coupling to $\pi$ and $h$.

I assume that the only terms that matter in answering this question are:

$$
\overline{\psi} i \gamma_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \psi - g \left( \overline{\psi}_L \psi_R \phi + \overline{\psi}_R \psi_L \phi^* \right)
$$

Now, let's expand this term as follows:

$$
\overline{\psi} i \gamma_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \psi - g \left( \overline{\psi}_L \psi_R \left( (v + h) e^{i \frac{\pi}{f}} \right) + \overline{\psi}_R \psi_L \left( (v + h) e^{-i \frac{\pi}{f}} \right) \right)
$$

The challenge here is to determine the fermion mass. My idea is to write a Lagrangian equivalent to the Dirac Lagrangian, where the constant $c$ that should appear in the Lagrangian, i.e., $c \overline{\psi} \psi$, represents the mass. However, I can't find such a term in the Lagrangian we have. To proceed, I first rewrite $\psi_{L,R}$ in terms of $\psi$ itself, resulting in:

$$
- g (v+h) \overline{\psi} \left( \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{f}\right) + i \gamma^5 \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{f}\right) \right) \psi
$$

Next, I expand the trigonometric expressions to obtain:

$$
g (v+h) \overline{\psi} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\pi}{f}\right)^2 + i \gamma^5 \frac{\pi}{f} \right) \psi
$$

This expansion results in terms such as:

$$
- g v \overline{\psi} \psi - g h \overline{\psi} \psi - \frac{i g v \gamma^5}{f} \overline{\psi} \pi \psi + \frac{g v}{2 f^2} \overline{\psi} \pi \pi \psi + O(\ldots)
$$

So, the fermion mass would be $g v$, the coupling $h \psi \overline{\psi}$ would be $g$, and the $\overline{\psi} \pi \psi$ coupling would be $\frac{i g v \gamma^5}{f}$?

Comment: It would be easier to read if you use exp(...) instead of $e^{(...)}$.

Comment: @flippiefanus ok

Comment: Basically, but what does $\gamma^5$ outside the fermion bilinear mean? This is an elementary homework problem.

Comment: @CosmasZachos It can be elementary indeed, but i can't see yet what it can be. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: $\gamma^5$ is a matrix with spinor indices, so it is meaningless outside the fermion bilinear. The meaningful  term from your master expression, instead,  is $igv\pi \bar \psi \gamma^5\psi/f$.